# crystal report hierachical grouping options if part is repeat

Tags: crystal-reports

I encounter a question about crystal report how to group by ?

I have a table named Part

```
   Part_ID   Parent_Part_ID
    B             A
    c             A
    A             NULL
    C             B
    D             B
    E             C
    F             C
```

A is a top part, B,C,D not only sub part but also are parent part, E,F are lowest sub part.

Now ,I need to show From Parent_part to Part with Levels,Like This[image]

How Can I show this format data in Crystal report

I try use `hierachical grouping options` ,but the result is not i want

[image]

I need the result is:

```
 A 
   B
     C   (shold be show even the part have two parent part)
      E
      F
    D
  C
    E
    F
```

Comment: jack did you try my solution?

Comment: I try your solution ,but there are still a questoion,it cannont show C where parent_part is B

Comment: look at the new solution.. problem solved!

Comment: Your solution is great but limited ,to my question ,the level is dynamic and uncertain,Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### SOLVED!

Tried menu voice called `hierachical grouping options` and specified the field that links each record to his parent.

The result should look similar to this:

```
A
  B
    C
      E
      F
    D
  C
    E
    F
```

**But Crystal Reports Hierarchies take each record just once, and don't care if same element should be under two parents.**

So i made a query-hack, **creating hierarchy directly in the data using a JOIN on the same table based on Parent Item**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Part_ID varchar(1), Parent_Part_ID varchar(1) );
insert into @t 
SELECT 'B' , 'A'  
UNION   SELECT 'C'   ,   'A' 
UNION   SELECT 'A'   ,  NULL 
UNION   SELECT 'C'   ,   'B' 
UNION   SELECT 'D'  ,    'B' 
UNION   SELECT 'E'    ,  'C' 
UNION   SELECT 'F'    ,  'C' 

SELECT 
 t1.Part_ID as t1, 
 t2.Part_ID as t2, 
 t3.Part_ID as t3, 
 t4.Part_ID as t4
FROM @t t1 
  LEFT JOIN @t t2 on t1.Part_ID = t2.Parent_Part_ID
  LEFT JOIN @t t3 on t2.Part_ID = t3.Parent_Part_ID
  LEFT JOIN @t t4 on t3.Part_ID = t4.Parent_Part_ID
WHERE t1.Parent_Part_ID is null
```

and **removed hierarchical grouping options, just created 3 groups on t1, t2, t3** using header for each group and using details for t4.

The result is, as needed,

```
A
 B
  C
   E
   F
  D
 C
  E
  F
```

[Here the .rpt](http://beativoi.altervista.org/opentech/Hierarchy.rpt)  if someone needs it.

Comment: I try your solution,but result not I want,

Comment: You right @jack.li the result looks like the one you wrote, not the one I wrote. Crystal Reports takes each record only once and appends it to the first parent found.

Comment: Thanks your solution .there is no way to finish this function?

Comment: Your solution is great but limited ,to my question ,the level is dynamic and uncertain,Thanks

Comment: @jack.li you can make a query with many JOINs (20? 50?) to cover any possible raquirement from data. You have to make the same number of groups in the report. Hiding empty sections the report will adapt to real data. This is a workaround but can solve your problem.